# Shortcode to Strip Tags of Custom Fields Based on Shortcode attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

**Question Background**

I created a group of custom fields, e.g. `person-given-name`, `person-last-name` and `person-job-title`. These custom fields contain `html`. I want to show their content as plain text in a specific place on my webpage. The custom fields are created by a plugin called `Toolset Types` and the plugin has a built-in function to display the contents of the custom field: `types_render_field( "custom-field-slug", array());`

To do so effectively, I wanted to create a shortcode with an attribute, whereby when I add the field name in the attribute, the `strip_tags` will be applied to that custom field, and `return` the plain text content of the custom field.

**Initial Function**

The following function works for one field only.

```
function add_person_data() {
    if( function_exists( 'types_render_field' ) ){
        $input = types_render_field( "person-job-title", array());
        $a = strip_tags($input);
    return $a;      
    }
}
    add_shortcode( 'add-person-data', 'add_person_data');
```

**Updated Function**

I tried to expand the function to have a shortcode attribute, where I can specify which custom field I want to apply `strip_tags` on and display.

The function did not give errors in the `php-error.log`, but does not `return` any values. This is the shortcode I used `[add-person-data field="givenname"]`.

```
function add_person_data($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'field' => '',
        ),
        $atts
    );

    if( function_exists( 'types_render_field' ) ){

        $person_info = array_filter( array (
                    'givenname'       => types_render_field( "person-given-name", array () ),
                    'familyname'      => types_render_field( "person-family-name", array () ),
                    'jobtitle'      => types_render_field( "person-honorific-suffix", array () ),
                    ) );
        foreach ( $person_info as $prop => $value ) {
                    $a = strip_tags($person_info['field']);                 
                    }                   
        return $a;
    }
}
    add_shortcode( 'add-person-data', 'add_person_data');
```

Can someone please point me to the mistakes I am doing, so I can fix the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try remove function_exists and check error.

Comment: Are you using the advanced custom fields plugin?

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. I am using the `Toolset Types` plugin (similar to ACF), and I removed the `function_exists`, but still the error log doesn't show any error, and no value is displayed in the frontend.

Comment: Try var_dump($a) and provide here.

Comment: Where you execute [add-person-data field="givenname"] ?

Comment: if you run shortcode in template you should use - echo do_shortcode('[add-person-data field="givenname"]')

Comment: @Dmitry: Currently I have execute the shortcode in the post content area, but the final destination will be in the `wp_head`. Here is the `var_dump$a)` results:
`string(0) "" string(0) ""` (it showed at the top of the page)

Comment: Could please provide var_dump($person_info) ?

Comment: I've founded problem $person_info['field'] - is empty.

Comment: the `var_dump($person_info)` is: `array(1) { ["givenName"]=> string(8) "John Doe" } array(1) { ["givenName"]=> string(8) "John Doe" }`

Comment: What you need output from shortcode?

Comment: the custom field will have: `<a href="https://example.com/url">John Doe</a>` and I want the shortcode to return `John Doe` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use code below:

```
function add_person_data($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'field' => 'givenname', 
        ),
        $atts
    );

    $a = '';

    if( function_exists( 'types_render_field' ) ){

        $person_info = array_filter( array (
            'givenname'       => types_render_field( "person-given-name", array () ),
            'familyname'      => types_render_field( "person-family-name", array () ),
            'jobtitle'      => types_render_field( "person-honorific-suffix", array () ),
        ) );
        $a = $person_info[$atts['field']];
        $b = strip_tags($a);
        return $b;
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'add-person-data', 'add_person_data');
```

Comment: Thanks. This code gives me `John Doe`, whether I used the attribute `givenname` or not. Also, how to add the other custom fields? i.e. `person-family-name`..etc? Do I specify more variables? `b`, `c`? But then how to call them in the shortcode?

Comment: the change to `$value` made the outcome just the letter `J`, with or without the attribute.

Comment: I don't want html.. All what I want is when I add `[add-person-data field="givenname"]`, I get `John Doe`, and when I add `[add-person-data field="jobtitle"]`, i get `Web Developer`..etc Just the custom field content `without` any html in it.

Comment: Thanks. This edit made the outcome: `J J J`, with and without the shortcode attribute.

Comment: No, all what it gives is the letter `J` 3 times. `J` is the first letter from `john Doe`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Getting there. The only problem is that this new code returns all the fields written in the same line. I don't want to display them as a sentence. I want only to display the custom field that I specify in the shortcode. Currently all fields display whether there is a shortcode attribute or not.

Comment: I got it and I edited my answer again. Check please.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This last code returns the correct values, but still with html becasue you removed the `strip_tags`, so I modified your answer with this code and it now works `$b = strip_tags($a);
 return $b;`. Cheers.

Comment: Can you please modify your answer using the modification I mentioned, so I can accept it as the answer and other people can benefit? thanks